# What does {{var}} in batch script mean

Tags: batch-file

I have something like {{var}} in my script, but it is not declared anywhere in that file. Could someone help me?

I knew that for environmental variables we use like %var% but not sure what {{var}} this mean.

Here my batch file is calling SQL SP.

Script is like this

```
echo "sql_server is {{target_sql_server}}"
```

I am very new to scripting and i did not find anywhere what this means.

and in

```
sqlcmd -s {{target_sql_server}}
```

Comment: The curly braces have no special meaning to cmd.exe.  It is just text.  Might want to tag your question with SQL to find out if it means something.

Comment: also showing us the thing in context may help us helping you.

Comment: Edited, please have a look.

Comment: in the `echo` line, the string is just written to the screen (as Squashman said: curly braces have no special meaning to cmd.exe. In your `sqlcmd` line, it may have a special meaning to SQL. Add the appropriate `SQL` tag to get help by SQL people.

Comment: Is something else (some other language/tech) *wrapping* this batch script? If so, its probably some form of replacement mechanism in *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer for my question :)

{{var}} is a placeholder where value gets replaced during the time of deployment.

Where as %var% puts the value during run time.